# addMonths fns is not returning correct UTC time

Tags: javascript, timezone, date-fns

I'm currently based in `Central European Standard Time` and I'm expecting to send all dates to the server converted back to `UTC`.

I have tried simply using `addMonths` from `date-fns` library:

```js
import addMonths from "date-fns/addMonths";

const now = new Date();
// Sat Mar 05 2022 13:56:04 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)
console.log(now);
const oneMonthFromNow = addMonths(now, 1);
// 2022-04-05T11:56:04.189Z
console.log(oneMonthFromNow.toISOString());
```

The difference between `CEST` and `UTC` is simply one hour. I'm expecting to have an hour and one month difference between `now` and `oneMonthFromNOw` but it ends up having one month and two hours difference.

What I would expect:

```js
import addMonths from "date-fns/addMonths";

const now = new Date();
// Sat Mar 05 2022 13:56:04 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)
console.log(now);
const oneMonthFromNow = addMonths(now, 1);
// Since CEST time is 13:56:04 I would expect to get 12:56:04 (1 hour difference only)
// But I end up getting 2022-04-05T12:56:04.189Z
console.log(oneMonthFromNow.toISOString());
```

Am I missunderstanding something here? Shouldn't I get one month and one hour difference between `now` and `oneMonthFromNow`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The difference between CEST and UTC is simply one hour.

---

The difference is two hours: Central European Summer Time (CEST, UTC+02:00).

---

You went from CET time (one hour ahead) on Mar 05 2022 to CEST summer time (two hours ahead) on 2022-04-05.

---

> Central European Time (CET) is a standard time which is 1 hour ahead
> of Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).
>
> As of 2011, all member states of the European Union observe summer
> time (daylight saving time), from the last Sunday in March to the last
> Sunday in October. States within the CET area switch to Central
> European Summer Time (CEST, UTC+02:00) for the summer.
>
> [Wikipedia: Central European
> Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_European_Time)
>
> [Wikipedia: Central European Summer
> Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_European_Summer_Time)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Whenever I go to Google and search for `Berlin time` (CEST) and then search for `Lisbon time` (UTC) it gives me a difference of one hour between `Berlin` and `Lisbon`. Do you know why its contradicting your answer?

Comment: @null: It confirms, not contradicts my answer. Germany and Portugal are member states of the European Union. As I said in my answer, they synchronize their observation of daylight saving time: "all member states of the European Union observe summer time (daylight saving time), from the last Sunday in March to the last Sunday in October." Therefore, for the same day, they are always one hour apart. [Time in Germany: UTC+01:00](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Germany). [Time in Portugal:  UTC+00:00](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Portugal). There is no contradiction,

Comment: @null: Compare like with like: CET UTC+01:00 (Berlin) versus WET UTC+00:00 (Lisbon) and CEST UTC+02:00 (Berlin) versus WEST UTC+01:00 (Lisbon). There is no contradiction.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @rocka2q. Now I understand the differences